# How to Enable/Disable an ElevatedButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Does anybody know how to enable/disable a Flutter ElevatedButton? I've reviewed the documentation but I can't see anything that is obvious.

```
class IcoButton extends StatelessWidget {
    IcoButton(
      {@required this.lbl,
      @required this.col,
      @required this.ico,
      @required this.onPress});

  final String lbl;
  final FaIcon ico;
  final MaterialColor col;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      label: Text(lbl),
      icon: ico,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: col,
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
        minimumSize: Size(160.0, 60.0),
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPress,
    );
     }
    }
```

Comment: Setting onPress to null might help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Passing null to the onPressed callback will disable the button.

`If onPressed and onLongPress callbacks are null, then the button will be disabled.`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html

Answer (score 19):

I use a member variable "_isDisable" to enable button or not. Put below code in the **build** function to init the view:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: _isDisable? null : callBackFunction,
  child: Text("submit"),
  style: ButtonStyle(),
);
```

when you want to disable button, call

```
setState(() {
  _isDisable = true;
});
```

when you want to enable button, call

```
setState(() {
  _isDisable = false;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, setting the `onPressed` callback to `null` will deactivate the button for you.

Note however that it is the callback itself that must be null, not its return, so like this:

```
onPressed: null,
```

And **not** like this

```
onPressed: () => null,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onPressed: () {
   if (isDisabled == true) { return; }

    setState(() { int a = 10; });
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this does.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is by passing null to the onPress callback as @Shannon and @ASAD HAMEED have mentioned. However, the AbsorbPointer widget is also worth a look.

Comment: Despite the negative votes the AbsorbPointer widget is still worth a look.